How to cat text string and file in bash in way to preserve literal \newpage in output?
I have multiple markdown files that I am trying to concatenate into one markdown file in bash. I can concatenate markdown files and preserve “\newpage” lines, but when trying to add a group title via a string calling echo to each group it wont preserve literal \newpage in file. I am bash beginner and learning as I go. How can I achieve this without making a file just storing group name with \newpage?
Examples of a single item in single markdown file
## Item 1 of group 1

Text to item 1 of group 1.

\newpage

## Item 2 of group 1

Text to item 2 of group 1.

\newpage

## Item 1 of group 2

Text to item 1 of group 2.

\newpage

Desired output after grouping all items under one group and adding a group title “Title of group 1” with \newpage at the end
# Title of group 1

\newpage

## Item 1 of group 1

Text to item 1 of group 1.

\newpage

## Item 2 of group 1

Text to item 2 of group 1.

\newpage

# Title of group 2

\newpage

## Item 1 of group 2

Text to item 2 of group 2.

\newpage

I can group items into each groups markdown file by using following code (this part works and \newpage is preserved:
dir_in="/path/do/input_directory/"
dir_out="/path/do/output_directory/"
file="group_1"
for f in ${dir_in}${file}/*.md; do cat $f >> ${dir_out}${file}.md; echo >> ${dir_out}${file}.md; done


How should I edit the code above so I could add a group name  “# Title of group 1 \newpage” from string variable?

I tried making a title into a variable and echo with content of grouped markdown file.
title="#Title of group 1 \newpage"
content=$(cat "${dir_out}${file}.md")
result=$(echo "${title}\n\n${content}")
echo "$result" > ${dir_out}${file}.md

But echo interprets every \n and prints newlines out and leaves “ewpages" into file.
#Title of group 1

ewpage


the expected output appears to have 3 items; please update the question to include the names and contents of the files that these 3 items come from

is dir_in and dir_out supposed to point to the same directory? you're reading from *.md files and writing to *.md files; what do you think happens if you run your script twice?

how do you determine the group number? is it based on the file name? is it based on parsing the contents of the .md files? or is there some other method for determing the group number?

@markp-fuso Added 3 examples of .md files that are shown in output. Corrected dir_in and dir_out. Groups are numbered for clarification. In reality they are names (foo, bar, etc). All items belonging to particular group are in folder named after the group. I will build a for loop over all folders (hence groups), make it a variable and name the group name in .md file after it. It is not present in here, just to keep it as brief as possible and I still working on it. Here the problem lies that I do not understand how to \newpage into file preserving the \n so it would be interpreted in markdown.

Try using an escape char, in your case would be title='#Title of group 1 \\newpage'
as stated at GNU documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html#:~:text=A%20non%2Dquoted%20backslash%20'%20%5C,with%20the%20exception%20of%20newline%20. From here I think you can go by yourself right? _ol

$ title='#Title of group 1 \newpage'
$ printf '%s\n' "$title"
#Title of group 1 \newpage
$

See why-is-printf-better-than-echo to learn about the problems with echo, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes to learn when to use single vs double vs no quotes and always run your code through http://shellcheck.net until you get more familiar with shell programming.

Assumptions/Understandings:

under ${dir_in} is a set of subdirectories
the names of these subdirectories are also what OP refers to as 'group' names
we are to create a new *.md file that consists of a group header followed by the contents of all files under the 'group' subdirectory

We're not given a complete view of the inputs (ie, don't know the directory/group names nor the *.md filenames) so I've waved the magic wand to come up with the following:
$ ls -l
drwxrwx---+ 1 username None   0 May 25 15:29 group1/
drwxrwx---+ 1 username None   0 May 25 15:29 group2/

$ ls -l group*
group1:
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 59 May 25 15:29 item1.md
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 59 May 25 15:29 item2.md

group2:
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 59 May 25 15:29 item1.md

$ head group*/*md
==> group1/item1.md <==
## Item 1 of group 1

Text to item 1 of group 1.

\newpage

==> group1/item2.md <==
## Item 2 of group 1

Text to item 2 of group 1.

\newpage

==> group2/item1.md <==
## Item 1 of group 2

Text to item 1 of group 2.

\newpage

There are several ways to slice-n-dice this (eg, bash, awk, python) but for this answer we'll stick with a bash solution:
dir_in=.
dir_out=.

for group in "${dir_in}"/*
do
    [[ ! -d "${group}" ]] && continue

    outfile="${dir_out}/${group}.md"

    printf '# Title of group %s\n\n\\newpage\n' "${group##*/}" > "${outfile}"

    for mdfile in "${group}"/*.md
    do
        echo ""
        cat "${mdfile}"
    done >> "${outfile}"
done

NOTE: we'll use printf as this tends to be easier to process special characters (eg, \n) and escape sequences (\\newpage => \newpage)
Results:
$ ls -l
drwxrwx---+ 1 username None   0 May 25 15:29 group1/
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 154 May 25 15:34 group1.md
drwxrwx---+ 1 username None   0 May 25 15:29 group2/
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None  94 May 25 15:34 group2.md

$ cat group1.md
# Title of group group1

\newpage

## Item 1 of group 1

Text to item 1 of group 1.

\newpage

## Item 2 of group 1

Text to item 2 of group 1.

\newpage

$ cat group2.md
# Title of group group2

\newpage

## Item 1 of group 2

Text to item 1 of group 2.

\newpage

